# Appending values to a Meta Array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to append data to a meta array with 2 axes. I have to continuously sample data and send this to a plot, so I'm storing it in a MetaArray. But I can't seem to figure out how to code that.

This is the structure I'm trying to append:

```
data = random.normal(size=(4, 1000)) * np.array([[0.1], [1e-5], [1], [4]])
time = linspace(0., 1., 1000)
info = [{'name': 'Signal', 'cols': [
         {'name': 'Voltage1', 'units': 'V'}, 
         {'name': 'Voltage2', 'units': 'V'}, 
         {'name': 'Current1', 'units': 'A'},
         {'name': 'Current2', 'units': 'A'},
        ]}, 
         {'name': 'Time', 'values': time, 'units': 's'}
        ]
ma = MetaArray(data, info)
```

When I try to append the 'Time' axis i get an exception due to wrong size.

Comment: Share the error message here too please

Comment: ``` DataPlots.ma.append(1,'Time') ```

 yields


Values array for axis 1 has incorrect shape. (given (1000,), but should be (1001,))

Comment: Have you tried changing `size=(4, 1000)` to `size=(4, 1001)` ?

Comment: problem is I need to continuously add data to it, so if I change it to 1001 it can hold 1001 values but I still can't append additional ones during runtime

Comment: What is this `MetaArray`?  Are you missing a tag?

Comment: Yes, I did forget the scipy flag, sorry

Comment: Why do you use the pyqt tag ?, I do not see anything in your question that depends on pyqt, your project may depend on pyqt but your question does not.